# Angular expression {{something || "<something>"}} breaks parser

Tags: angularjs

In my template, if a scope property is not available I would like to print a default:

`{{myProperty || "default"}}`

I was playing around with the `"default"` string a little bit and realized that angle brackets `<...>` cause the parser to break on that expression.

So this

`{{myProperty || "<default>"}}`

will not be angularized.

See plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/emxAdksZs5TGYz9Q84cI?p=preview

I can't find anything in the doc regarding this. Seems to me the parser should just pass string literals as are, but i guess not. Anyone know what's happening?

Comment: It's interpreting as html, replace `<something>` with `<i>` and you'll see. So since there is no tag <something> (or directive) than it displays nothing. Same for all other variations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the issue might actually be with the browser. If you notice the third h2 tag in the DOM looks like this:

```
<h2>Say something: {{something || "<something>"}}</something></h2>
```

So it looks like the browser is interpreting the string as an HTML tag. You will need to do what John said and escape the tags. Or you can also set the default on your controller, it will get interpreted correctly by angular there.

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('AppController', function($scope){
  $scope.something = undefined || "<something>";

});
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/6uzw50CnAkQ5bc0m7YHp?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

No clue why the parser barfs on that, but I can tell you that &lt; and &gt; work as well to replace the < and > symbols as an alternative.

Comment: A best practice would be to html escape all string literals used in this fashion.

Answer (score 0):

As alluded by others, the issue is caused by the browser, and the browser's attempt to fix the DOM.

This HTML `<h2>Say something: {{something || "something"}}</h2>`

is put in the DOM tree as follows

```
h2 node
  text node //=> Say something: {{something || "something"}}
```

once the DOM is built, angular comes by and reads the text node for markup expressions.

with this HTML: `Say something: {{something || "<a>"}}`
the DOM tree looks like:

```
h2 node
  text node //=> Say something: {{something || "
  <a> node
  text node //=> "}}
```

The text node is no longer together and therefore there is no valid angular curly-brace expression to process, hence angular does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, quotes have no special meaning to the parser outside of a tag, thus the angle brackets are read as a new tag. The angle brackets break your code, not the parser.